# Windows 8 RTM regedit.exe fails to execute like a program

Tags: windows-8

I want to edit the registry but Windows gives an error when I start `regedit.exe` as a standard user or administrator.

Hopefully this isn't an installation error or some new feature?

Comment: What is the error it is giving you? I can get into regedit on all my Win8 boxes.

Comment: I will tell you later. I need to reboot and check again with process.exe but when I click the .exe it gives not much.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the integrity of your regedit.exe file. Consider copying regedit.exe from a known working Windows 8 computer.